# How to display the result by columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have a few similar queries. And want to get result by columns. Is it possible? I what way? Is it the right syntax for "UNION"?

Example:

```
select(
(select total, amount FROM table_1 where sale_type = "type_1" GROUP BY 
total WITH ROLLUP),
(select total, amount FROM table_1 where sale_type = "type_2" GROUP BY 
total WITH ROLLUP),
(select total, amount FROM table_1 where sale_type = "type_3" GROUP BY 
total WITH ROLLUP),
(select total, amount FROM table_1 where sale_type = 
"type_4" GROUP BY 
total WITH ROLLUP),ORDER BY total);
```

Thanks!

Table of results:

```
 total    type_1     type_2   type_3   type_4
  ...      ...        ...      ...      ...
```

Comment: Please include some sample data which explains your question.

Comment: You didn't include data, you included a complex query with zero explanation.  Please teach us about your question by showing samplw input data, and the expected output.  And explain how we get that output if you think it would not be obvious.

Comment: Please show actual sample input data from the `table_1` table.  Then show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is speculative, because you did not show us any sample data, but I might suggest that you want conditional sums based on the `sale_type`.  If so, then the following query should be along the lines of what you want:

```
SELECT
    total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sale_type = 'type_1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sale_type = 'type_2' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sale_type = 'type_3' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sale_type = 'type_4' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sum_4
FROM table_1
GROUP BY total WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: thanks. In practice my query is more difficult. It is the same accept sales_type. I updated. May be I need to repeat this query , changing sale_type and use UNION?

Comment: if I don't need sum, what query is better to do?

Comment: I added a form of a table of results